# What is azure StormCloud?

Tags: azure

In my azure portal I see that I apparently have GBP95 credit for my StormCloud subscription, but what is it?
There's nothing to say what it actually is - it's as if I should know, but I don't.
Am I just being an Azure n00b?
Thx

Comment: /sigh thx for the downvotes, most helpful, no really, thx

Comment: Regarding the downvotes: You asked a non-programming, off-topic question for StackOverflow. And you're asking why you have a credit in some subscription. Not that it would help (since it's off-topic), but you didn't even include a screenshot. FYI Azure has no feature called StormCloud.

Comment: Thx David - I appreciate your time. Just glad I'm not a first-time user, even if my question suggested I might be. My azure billing page lists StormCloud, and google hasn't shed any light thus why I asked asked here - sorry this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: Via the azure portal you can open a free billing support ticket. They should be able to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

n00b!

StormCloud is a name I must've come up with one Friday afternoon months ago. It's nothing other than a cosmetic label in Azure billing - thus why I could find nothing on teh webs.

Thanks BrentDaCodeMonkey and David, everyone else please keep calm and carry on.